# How to find/calculate the shaded area of this shape in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a python program to calculate the shaded area of the circle in this picture:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is the input and output:

```
Enter the radius of a circle: 10
Enter the side of square :3
Enter the width of a rectangle :4
Enter the length of a rectangle :2 

The shaded area is : 12.0
```

Here is my code:

```
PI = 3.14
radius = float(input("Enter the radius of a circle:"))
area = PI * radius ** 2
    
side = int(input("Enter the side of square:"))
area = side*side
 
width = float(input("Enter the width of a rectangle:"))
length = float(input("Enter the length of a rectangle:"))

area = width * length
perimeter = (width + length) * 2
    
print("The shaded area is :", perimeter)
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong? Could you provide example input and expected output?

Comment: But... what is shaded area in your case? Do all your shapes has the center in one point?

Comment: Input :  Enter the radius of a circle: 10,  Enter the side of square :3, Enter the width of a rectangle :4,  Enter the length of a rectangle :2.    
Output :  The shaded area is : 12.0

Comment: Now it's much more clear but no in 100% - what is a relation of square and rectancle? Can they intersect? Or can they move outside circle?

Comment: @kosciej16 i posted the picture where i should run this program and with the values given the output is not right.

Comment: This is my task : Allow the user to enter the dimensions of shapes shown below (in cm), then calculate the area of
the blue shaded part. Note: The square and rectangular areas are empty.

Comment: In the picture shaded area is just circle_area - square_idea - rect_area. Is it what you expect for any data?

Comment: what do u mean for any data? if u mean the input doesn't matter.

Comment: You should be using the constant `M_PI` from math.h

Comment: @Gelly Look at your picture. What if side of square (`sw`) will be so big that it will move outside of circle? Or `rw` will be so big that it touch the square? Or `radius` will be smaller that `sw`? There are two options. 1) It can't happen in the problem you have. Then shaded area is what I wrote earlier. 2) It CAN happen. If so, we need to know coordinates of the center of square, center of rectangle and center of circle to make proper calculations.

Answer (score 2):

## **Problem**

You are overwriting the value of `area` and the previous assigned values are lost.

**Example**

```
area = input('enter first value')
10
# the value of area is 10
area = input('enter second value')
3
# the value of area is now 3 and 10 is lost
```

However you can use `area -= number` or `area += number` to substract or add a number to the current value of the variable like so:

```
area = input('enter first value')
10
# the value of area is 10
area -= input('enter second value')
3
# the value of area is now 10 - 3 = 7
```

As correctly pointed out in the comments you should also `import math` and use `math.pi` instead of using the value `3.14`

The correct output for the shaded area is:

```
Enter the radius of a circle:10
Enter the side of square:3
Enter the width of a rectangle:4
Enter the length of a rectangle:2
The shaded area is : 297.1592653589793
>
```

I would recommend solution 1 as variables should have meaningful names (unlike solution 2):

- [Meaningful Variable Names](https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/intro-to-earth-data-science/write-efficient-python-code/intro-to-clean-code/expressive-variable-names-make-code-easier-to-read/)

and solution 3 is a bit harder to read and understand:

- [Make your code easy to read/understand](https://www.codementor.io/blog/pythonic-code-6yxqdoktzt)

## **Solution 1 (Using different variable names)**

```
import math 

def findDimensions():
    radius = float(input("Enter the radius of a circle:"))
    # radius = 10
    circle_area = math.pi * radius ** 2
    side = int(input("Enter the side of square:"))
    # side = 3
    square_area = side * side
    # but you could use square_area = side ** 2 as well
    width = float(input("Enter the width of a rectangle:"))
    # width = 4
    length = float(input("Enter the length of a rectangle:"))
    # length = 2
    rectangle_area = width * length
    shaded_area = circle_area - square_area - rectangle_area
    print("The shaded area is :", shaded_area)
findDimensions()
```

## **Solution 2 (Updating the `area` variable instead of overwriting it)**

```
import math 

def findDimensions():
    radius = float(input("Enter the radius of a circle:"))
    # radius = 10
    area = math.pi * radius ** 2
    side = int(input("Enter the side of square:"))
    # side = 3
    area -= side * side
    # but you could use area -= side ** 2 as well
    width = float(input("Enter the width of a rectangle:"))
    # width = 4
    length = float(input("Enter the length of a rectangle:"))
    # length = 2
    area -= width * length
    print("The shaded area is :", area)
findDimensions()
```

## **Solution 3 (Moving calculations to the end)**

```
import math 

def findDimensions():
    radius = float(input("Enter the radius of a circle:"))
    # radius = 10
    side = int(input("Enter the side of square:"))
    # side = 3
    width = float(input("Enter the width of a rectangle:"))
    # width = 4
    length = float(input("Enter the length of a rectangle:"))
    # length = 2
    shaded_area = (math.pi * radius ** 2) - (side * side) - (width * length)
    print("The shaded area is :", shaded_area)
findDimensions()
```

Comment: thanks you so much for the entire codes and explenations.

Comment: No problem and if you found it useful or if it solved your problem have a look at this: [What to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)